# jQuery - need to dynamically fill some Divs from json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json like this below and I need to dynamically fill some Divs

json

```
information:
  first:
    Image: image-1.jpg
    Title: title-1
    Text: text-1
  second:
    Image: image-2.jpg
    Title: title-2
    Text: text-2
   third:
    Image: image-3.jpg
    Title: title-3
    Text: text-3
```

html

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

How I need

```
<div class="article">
  <div class="image">image-1</div>
  <div class="title">title-1</div>
  <div class="text">text-1</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="image">image-2</div>
  <div class="title">title-2</div>
  <div class="text">text-2</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="image">image-3</div>
  <div class="title">title-3</div>
  <div class="text">text-3</div>
</div>
```

I already tried with "each" and "for", but it is not working properly, it ends up filling everything with all the info.

I only have my last code

```
for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
    var image = information[i].image;
    $('.article .image').append(image);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: lets see this each and for? maybe can work off of that.

Comment: `$('.item .image')` is a global selector.  It's going to select all the same things every time.  Also it's unclear in your snippet what `infos` and `item` are.

Comment: @GabrielDutra Give the json code without changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
    var image = information[i].image;
    $('.article').eq(i).find('.image').append(image);
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

In order to address your question specifically, the selector `$('.article .image')` returns an array of elements, which hopefully will match the length of your JSON. If so, you can use the same index to populate the HTML as such:

```
for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
    $($('.article .image')[i]).append(information[i].image);
    $($('.article .title')[i]).append(information[i].title);
    $($('.article .text')[i]).append(information[i].text);
}
```

Hope that helps :)

P.S. It would be a lot nicer if you would iterate through the object and insert the HTML blocks with the content, instead of pre-rendering HTML and populating it.

**EDIT**: Wrapped the HTML into JQuery elements after getting them.

Comment: `[i]` returns the underlying dom element.  `append()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: Edited to fix. :)

Comment: Use `eq(i)` instead of unwrapping and re-wrapping.